# I tried to create new sheet with name but facing issue

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub AddSheet()

Dim wkbSource As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Application.Screenupdating = False
Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open("C:\nani\Excel-Vba\test.xlsx")

Set ws = wkbSource.Sheets

ws.Add(Before:=Sheets(1)).Name = "FirstSheet"


End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of issues here

```
Sub AddSheet()

Dim wkbSource As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open("C:\nani\Excel-Vba\test.xlsx")

Set ws = wkbSource.Worksheets.Add(Before:= wkbSource.Sheets(1))
Ws.Name = "FirstSheet"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for answering... I thought about putting a comment and then just gave up.

Comment: Indentation is nice

Comment: @hack feel free to add it